# Yii2 make absolutes url default on application

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm looking for a way to set UrlManager component to return absolute urls by default. I know that we can get the absolute url using Url::to([], true).

Is there a way to customize the component and them make all urls absolute by once?

Thanks

Comment: Just override method `to()` in your `Url` class, which extends `Url` class from `Yii`?

Comment: @Yupik   post a proper answer  with  a code sample  .. you comment is a good answer  and the user seem not an expert..

Comment: @scaisEdge OOP is basics right now in PHP + OP didn't provided any code tries, so comment should just motivate OP to do some research and show us some effort from his side.

Comment: @Yupik  .. your opinion is correct  ..in past self-learning and the study of reference manuals was a common practice in the technical world. today it seems to me that the pradigma has changed, we learn more from cases than from a systematic study. What is the best method? self-learning was a necessity when platforms like OS were not available, today direct access to internet resources to what extent is not a form of self-approvement ?. however mine was just a suggestion.

Comment: @scaisEdge Well, true, but learning from cases doesn't excuse lazyness :) If OP just show us a little bit effort of self-trying - i've would be glad to help him :) Right now, most of cases here (not all ofc, and not exacly this question), are just "i want this and this, do it for me", here we just pointed OP what he should do, if he try and something won't work - we will fix it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overrule the default Url class.**

Place the class below somewhere in your project. Then add the following line to the `_bootstrap.php` file in common.

`Yii::$classMap['yii\helpers\Url'] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/components/Url.php';`

Url class:

```
<?php

namespace yii\helpers;

class Url extends \yii\helpers\BaseUrl {

    // Set the $scheme to be true by default.
    public static function to($url = '', $scheme = true) {
        return parent::to($url, $scheme);
    }

    // Set the $scheme to be true by default.
    public static function toRoute($route, $scheme = true) {
        return parent::toRoute($route, $scheme);
    }
}
```

By adding the line in the bootstrap file you're saying that everywhere you're loading `yii\helpers\Url` it should point to your own file instead of the one provided by the framework. This will make all URLs absolute, even the ones generated by other widgets (yii\widgets\Menu or anything).

With this setup you can still make a URL relative by setting false. e.g. `Url::to('/some/route', false)`